# Browser "render engine" and "javascript engine" to optimize testing

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

In order to minimize the testing of web applications I would like to know which version of a render engine or which javascript engine in which version is built into different browsers. 
E.g Safari is built on Webkit and JavaScriptCore.

Is there any overview available showing this kind of information?

The main reason for this question is, that we need to support chinese browser like baidu, QQ, UC, 360 and alike.

Comment: And you did not google about the same?

Comment: Of course I did. I googled for this but the only information I could get was the versions for Chrome and partially for Safari and Firefox.